# Selecting duplicate values based on distinct values in another column

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, so lets say I have a table comprising three columns. The first column is a unique id, the second is usernames, and the third is items users own.

What I would like to do is select values from the items row, that two distinct usernames posses. How might I go about doing that? So for hypothetical sake lets say I want to see what items both bob and ruth possess.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Is there a way i can post tables to give an example of what I'm talking about?

Comment: What do you mean the third column contains item **s**? Is it some sort of delimited list? If so this will be tricky unless you normalise your tables.

Comment: Is the items column a foreign key to a list of items? Can there exist two rows for the same username and item?

Comment: Hey guys, no, one user may own one item once. Both rows are foreign keys joining two tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what I think your table structure is...

```
SELECT i.itemid,
       i.description
FROM   items i
       JOIN useritemrelationship r
         ON i.itemid = r.itemid
       JOIN users u
         ON u.userid = r.userid
WHERE  u.name in ( 'Ruth', 'Bob' )
GROUP  BY i.itemid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT r.userid) = 2
```

Comment: Hi Martin, is there any chance you could explain that a little for me? What exactly does t1 and t2 signifiy?

Comment: No I haven't taken these into account as that is the first I've heard of them! Am I to assume something like `username (userid, name)` and `items (itemid, description)` and `useritemrelationship (userid,itemid)`

Comment: Yes precisely. Sorry for my bad descriptive ability's :(, you have no idea how much you are helping me out right now. I am currently working on the 4 extra reputation I need to upvote you. Lol.

Comment: Wow Martin. You know your stuff. Same question though, what exactly do i and u signify? Are these simply variable names that work within SQL?

Comment: @Ferdia - They are just table alias names to save some typing. You put them after the table names in the `FROM` or `JOIN` and then use the short names in the other parts of the query.

Comment: Awesome Martin. I up voted your answer. Once I've implemented it and checked that my bad descriptive abilities haven't made you mess up, I'll mark it as another win for you good sir.

Comment: Hey Martin. After I'd swapped out the hypotheticals for the real attribute names and tested it, that didnt actually work. I did some messing around to try and fix it, and it turned out that removing "DISTINCT" actually fixed it. No idea why, but I thought I'd give you the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest creating a new table for the items with at least three fields: itemID (if the item names aren't unique), itemName, and ownerID. Then query from the new table:

```
SELECT itemName FROM items WHERE ownerID='ruths id' OR ownerID='bobs ID'
```

This would also help implement normalization which is generally a clean/organized etiquette to follow when establishing a database.

Comment: Well how I have it set up is I have a table that describes the items, including name, and the item ID is transfered into the table I described above using a foreign key. The table I am searching is for each instance of ownership of an item in the other table. So this table exists to define the relationship between the users table, and the items table.